# Serving secure static S3 site without www

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to set up AWS to serve a static S3 site over SSL with a custom domain. I'm *so* close but I'm missing one piece.

S3 static website (works): xyz.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com

CloudFront distribution: abc.cloudfront.net w/SSL cert from Certificate Manager for mydomain.com with behavior of Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

DNS (GoDaddy): CNAME www abc.cloudfront.net

- https://www.example.com/ works perfectly
- https://example.com/ does not (privacy error)
- http://www.example.com/ redirects to https abc.cloudfront.net
- http://example.com/ redirects to https abc.cloudfront.net

The cert is set up for both www and none.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you checked binding settings ?

Comment: @Aravinda Can you be more specific please?

Comment: what is the websrver used ?

Comment: @Aravinda There is no web server. This is hosting static files directly from an S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create another CloudFront Distribution and another S3 Bucket (www-bucket). You can use your current SSL certificate since you mentioned it's valid for both none and www

Read about redirecting from your www-bucket to the main bucket - [How Do I Redirect Requests to an S3 Bucket Hosted Website to Another Host?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/redirect-website-requests.html)

You can use this CloudFormation template [cloudformation-s3-website-ssl-with-redirect](https://github.com/rogerchi/cloudformation-s3-website-ssl-with-redirect/blob/master/cloudformation-s3-website-ssl-with-redirect.yaml)  to implement this solution.

You can also read this nice blog post - [How to do Site redirection using AWS S3?](https://medium.com/tensult/how-to-do-site-redirection-using-aws-522a4002c645)